# Stop the same window from opening twice OS X app

Tags: swift, macos

How do I prevent a window from opening twice? I basically want to check all the open windows in my app and see if there is a specific vc open already. If it is open, I want to bring that window/vc to the front and highlight it. if an instance of that window/vc is not open then I want to trigger the segue to open that window. Right now if I click a button, a new instance of the same window opens but that is a bad experience because it is already open.

Comment: `a new instance of the same window` - do you mean a duplicate window?

Comment: yes a duplicate window

Comment: right now I am triggering a segue when a button is tapped to open a new window if I click the button twice two copies of the same window open obviously. I the new window to open the first time the window is opened but the second time I want the already open window to be highlighted instead of an duplicate of the window getting opened

Comment: Then just iterate over the existing windows and find out if one of them isn't already presenting the data

Comment: I am using a show segue if that makes any difference

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: There are plenty questions on SO that can help you in this new endeavour.

Comment: Is this a window that you have closed? Or a window that still exists and you just navigated away?

Comment: @KaylaGalway a window that still exists but have navigated away.

Comment: Okay, navigation controllers have a property called viewControllers - this holds everything in the navigation stack (all view controllers you have opened that were not popped from the stack) - try to solve the issue knowing this and post your attempt. You can search stack overflow to figure out more about this too. You may want to iterate through that stack and check each item to see if it is whatever specific type of `UIViewController` class you are looking for?

Comment: this is an OS X issue not an iOS issue and I don't think the navigation controller exists in OS X apps

Comment: but I want to highlight the window or bring it as a main window when it is open instead of just alerting the user that it is open

Comment: ah my bad @NevinJethmalani I thought it was iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually no code required for this and there is a simple solution.

1. In your storyboard, select the destination VC that you are segueing to.
2. Open the attributes inspector and change `Presentation` from `Multiple` to `Single`.

Comment: You mean the destination WindowController

Comment: In my case it was a view controller I was segueing to not a window controller. I am new to OS X development so I am not sure whether it is best practice to embed every VC in a window controller but I didn't embed this VC in a WindowController and it is working fine.

Comment: It will depend on your needs